# Correct syntax to run Curl for Benzinga

Tags: curl

I'm following the Benzinga docs and I'm running into errors. The docs are located here: https://docs.benzinga.io/benzinga/newsfeed-v2.html I tried to run the sample command at the bottom of this page (after substituting in my API key):
https://docs.benzinga.io/benzinga/index.html  The command looks like (after taking out the \ and should be one line)

```
 curl -X GET 
 'http://api.benzinga.com/api/v2/calendar/ratings?token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE&ratings=Upgrades' 
 -H 'accept: application/json'
```

I tried to run this in a Windows 10 powershell and got the errors:

```
  Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "accept: 
 application/json" value of type "System.String" to type " 
 System.Collections.IDictionary".
 At line:1 char:124
 + ... xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&ratings=Upgrades'  -H 'accept: application/json'
 +                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], 
 ParameterBindingException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
 CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Try wrapping the headers in curly braces. `-H {'accept: application/json'}` Just a guess.

Comment: **PowerShell curl isn't.** If you just use the command `curl` in PS it actually runs the PS cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` (as you see in the error message) and although that does an HTTP or HTTPS request it is otherwise almost completely unlike curl. Either use `curl` in CMD (which doesn't do this) or use `curl.exe` in either CMD or PS. Or specify the path `\Windows\System32\curl` instead of just the commandname, but that's tedious.